# How to add Zend Guard Loader support in docker php official image instance?

Tags: php, deployment, docker, zend-guard, zend-loader

I want to add *Zend Guard Loader* support on my php instance.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/loader/downloads#Linux

Normally, I will download the package, and then add the following settings into `php.ini`

```
[Zend Guard Loader]
zend_extension="/usr/local/webserver/php/ext/ZendGuardLoader.so"
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=3
zend_loader.license_path="/var/developer.zl"
```

But, now I'm running the instance within docker.

```
docker run --name php_instance php:5-fpm
```

And I tried to get into the shell:

```
docker exec -it php_instance bash
```

But I cannot find the `php.ini`, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a command in your Dockerfile to copy the php.ini file from local to docker container?

Similar to

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

# Install system packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    libssh2-1 \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install xdebug

# Enable php extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_pgsql
RUN pecl install ssh2-1.1.2

# Copy custom php.ini file
ADD ./deployment/my.php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```